# strange indentation of fprintf in Erlang ports with C

Tags: c, erlang, printf, indentation, ports

I am learning Erlang currently. I am going through the book: Programming Erlang (2nd edition).

When I debug with fprintf in C (the first example in Ports), there is a strange indentation of the console in Erlang.

the code is [here](https://github.com/cjen07/ports), I am running like this:

```
g++ -o example1 example1.c erl_comm.c example1_driver.c
erl
c(example1).
example1:start().
example1:sum(1,2).
```

and I got:

```
3> example1:sum(1,2).
buff is 0 3
           calling sum 1 2
                          3
```

I am wondering why there is indentation in the output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because of the Erlang REPL switching output streams to raw mode. Try changing the `\n` to `\n\r` in the `fprintf` calls.

Comment: @Dogbert It works. Thanks very much!

Comment: Once had the same output issue in a NIF, which was solved the same way.